# MYSQL - COUNT BY GROUPing

Tags: mysql, group-by, count

assuming a table like this

```
domain       | city      | number
-------------|-----------|-------
example.com  | rome      | 11111 <--,
example1.com | rome      | 11111    |_ this two should be counted as 1
example2.com | rome      | 11111    |
example.com  | rome      | 11111 <--'
example.com  | amsterdam | 11111
example2.com | rome      | 22222
example.com  | uk        | 22222
example.com  | amsterdam | 22222 <--._ this two should be counted as 1
example.com  | amsterdam | 22222 <--'
```

i would like to output something like the following results  `11111, total = 4` and `22222, total = 3`

so far i have this query, but off course is not working! :(

```
SELECT number, COUNT(number) as total FROM table GROUP BY city, domain
```

Comment: Close try `COUNT(DISTINCT number)`

Comment: What is your PRIMARY KEY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `COUNT()` over a preprocessed table expression that eliminates duplicates, as in:

```
select number, count(*)
from (
  select distinct domain, city, number from my_table
) x
group by number
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `group by number`:

```
select number, count(distinct concat(domain, '-', city)) total
from tablename
group by number
```

result:

```
number  total
11111   4
22222   3
```

Comment: nice approach! ;-)